# Passing DataGridRow as Object to a Converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, converters

Once again I have a little problem with WPF, XAML and probably my own stupidity ;)
I have a DataGrid which is bound to the DataContext. The DataContext is an array of Objects from a Class I made myself (something simple like class Employee with Properties like FirstName, LastName, etc... really nothing special.)
I wanted to create a ToolTip for the rows, so I made a RowStyle where I assigned the ToolTip. It was first bound to a Property named 'Status'. The following code worked fine:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status Converter={StaticResource StatusToolTipConverter}}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

But then I changed my mind. I don't want to pass only the "Status" Property, now I want to pass the whole Object (Remember: one row = one object). Or in other words: I want to Pass the DataContext of the row to my converter. Since the Object that I want to pass is the DataContext itself, there shouldn't be much to change. So I changed it to:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StatusToolTipConverter}}"/>
```

Now here is where things start to go wrong. The converter gets 'null' as value. So I deleted the converter and tried it again. The ToolTip was correctly bound to the Object in the Row. I could proof that to myself because the correct Object name was shown in the tooltip. I even overwrote the .ToString() so that the Name of the Employee gets shown as Object name, which it did correctly without the converter.

so TL;DR: Why does the Converter get 'null' as Value, when the Object is bound correctly WITHOUT the converter?

Comment: And you are positively sure that `value` is null, not perhaps something like `value as string` (as it is still your old `StatusToolTipConverter`)?

Comment: Yep. it is null. If I hover the mouse over the object in the Parameterlist of public object Convert(object value, ....) it is null. The converter itself does currently nothing else than just 'return value' anyway. Everything else is commented out in the file.

Comment: VisualStudio Debugging output doesn't say anything out of order. The strange thing is that the converter gets called (breakpoint...), but as i said, no value.

Answer (score -1):

I found a little workaround. I made a property called 'Self' which returns 'this'. The ToolTip is now bound to 'Self'. It works.